# How do you transform a mesh with rig into another?

Tags: animation, objects, game-engine

how do you transform a mesh with rig into another, for example, a game or an animation of the Hulk, that transition between Dr and the monster, how do I make this transition of two totally different mesh’s? For objects, I know you have the Shrinkwrap option, but it doesn’t give me much control over the transition, thanks, you are beautiful, God bless you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create one armature and one mesh, and use shape keys to turn this mesh from one shape to the other. Of course, the Dr. Banner version of the mesh may need to be rather dense, so that when it grows into the Hulk, it still looks detailed and smooth. For that reason, you may find that your system doesn't perform well when animating, and so you might need a low-res Banner mesh AND a high res Banner mesh for turning into the Hulk, with the high res version keyframed invisible/unrenderable, and all the modifiers for it deactivated, until it is needed. Both versions of the mesh would be bound to the same rig. I don't recommend trying to create two rigs. If you need the rig itself to get larger also, as I imagine in this case you would, I would keyframe the scale of the armature as a whole in Object Mode to coincide with the shape key animation change. I don't believe this will break anything, but I've never done it before. So if anyone knows of any pitfalls to this, please weigh in.

Comment: it seems that what you give is the good solution: one unique armature that you scale, and shapekeys to transform the character. One thing though, what do you mean when you talk about a low-res and a high res, how would you use the high res?

Comment: The high res version would be keyframed invisible/unrenderable, with its modifiers set to not show in the viewport until the moment the transformation is to take place. At the onset of the transformation, the high res model would be keyframed on, and its modifiers would be switched on, while the low res version would be switched off, before continuing with the animation. This could improve playback performance on some machines. The two meshes have the same armature, so they will always be in the same place and position whenever the switching takes place.

Comment: mmh ok, still not sure about what you mean but anyway, armature size + shapekeys is the way to go  ;)